# Gulp concat outputs a file with import statements as well as exports with the same identifier?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp

gulpfile.js:

```js
const gulp = require("gulp");
const concat = require("gulp-concat");
const sass = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));
const ts = require("gulp-typescript");
const del = require("del");

const outputFolder = "dist";

const cleanWorkload = (cb) => {
  del.sync([outputFolder]);
  cb();
};

/* WORKLOADS */
const scssWorkload = () => gulp.src("src/scss/index.scss").pipe(sass()).pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolder));
const tsWorkload = () =>
  gulp
    .src("src/ts/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(
      ts({
        module: "es6",
        target: "es5",
        lib: ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
      })
    )
    .pipe(concat("tree.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolder));

/* DEFAULT */
const directCompilation = gulp.parallel(scssWorkload, tsWorkload);
gulp.task("default", gulp.series(cleanWorkload, directCompilation));

/* WATCH */
gulp.task("watch", () => {
  gulp.watch("src/scss/**/*.scss", scssWorkload);
  gulp.watch("src/ts/**/*.ts", tsWorkload);
});
```

snippet of the source file:

```js
import ElementCreator from "./helpers/ElementCreator";
import Branch from "./types/Branch.interface";
import BranchDescription from "./types/BranchDescription.interface";
import TreeConfig from "./types/TreeConfig.interface";

export default class Tree {
  private $el: HTMLElement;
  private branches: Branch[];
...
```

The problem is that when I run gulp the output file contains this:

```js
import ElementCreator from "./helpers/ElementCreator";
var Tree = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Tree(config) {
...

var ElementCreator = /** @class */ (function () {
    function ElementCreator() {
    }
...
```

And so the browser complains about ElementCreator already being declared

How do I tell gulp to remove all those import statements since the files are concatenated anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit more I found a somewhat feasible solution:
Firstly, you need to do `npm i gulp-strip-import-export`
Secondly, rewrite the `tsWorkload` as follows:

```js
const tsWorkload = () =>
  gulp
    .src("src/ts/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(
      ts({
        module: "es6",
        target: "esnext",
        lib: ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
      })
    )
    .pipe(stripImportExport())
    .pipe(babel({ presets: ["@babel/env"] }))
    .pipe(concat("tree.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolder));
```

Thirdly, in all your files use `export ClassName` instead of `export default ClassName`

By doing this all your js will be compiled into one file without any module system present at all
After that do:

```html
  <script src="/dist/tree.js"></script>
```

And all of the stuff you wrote will be readily available without any importing